# Nodetool getsstable for composite partition key

Tags: nodetool, cassandra-2.1

I've a table as following in keyspace test -

`CREATE TABLE mytable (
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  address text,
  phone text,
  PRIMARY KEY (firstname,lastname,address)
)`

I've inserted a record

```
insert into test.mytable(firstname,lastname,address,phone)  values ('H','P','Kolkata','9836852120');
```

and also have executed `nodetool compact test mytable` to force the record to go to sstable.

Now I'm want to execute `nodetool getsstables` for this record. How will I pass composite key in this command `nodetool getsstables test mytable <key>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you guys. Finally I figured it out myself. I first did a `list mytable` in cassandra-tcli, then took the RowKey value from the result and used it in the command `nodetool getsstables test mytable H:P:Kolkata`
So key will be `H:P:Kolkata`

If you have composite partition key then use `:` between them in sequence to find out the RowKey(PartitionKey).